# Call member function out of a static function

Tags: c++, lua

I just started messing around with Lua. Everything works just fine, but I've got a problem.
When I'm using `"lua_register"`, I have to pass a static function as the third parameter. But the problem is, that I want to call a member function from that static function. But the compiler says, that this is not possible.

Do you know a way how to do that?

Comment: Pass pointer or reference to an instance of the class as a parameter to that static function.

Comment: Depending on your code, you may or may not be able to go around this limitation with C++11 `std::bind` (or `boost::bind` for C++03).

Comment: @Petr Budnik, please post answers as answer.

Comment: What object do you want to call the member function on? Once you've answered that, the answer to the question should become obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either make member function static or pass an instance of the class to your static function and call its member.